# My Emacs substitute tab into whitespace automatically

Tags: unix, emacs, makefile

This has been bothering me, which hook should I check to prevent this from happening (which makes the Makefile fail)

Comment: If you edit your makefile in makefile-mode (which is the default), then it shouldn't do that.  If it still does, then it's something you've enabled in your emacs init file... we have no idea what you might have set up in your init file so we can't help.  If you run `emacs -q` then edit a makefile does it still convert?

Comment: Yes, makefile-mode has been enabled when I'm editing. The wired thing is that my emacs 'sometimes' do the substitution, I guess what happened is some hook includes the tab-to-whitespace command.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your init file:

```
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode  nil)
```

By default, that option is non-nil, which means that Emacs uses TAB chars when it can, instead of just SPC chars.

---

**Update after your comment:**

Maybe you have that code in your init file, but I suspect that other code that you are also using (e.g. loading or autoloading) sets the value to non-nil in your makefile buffer.

That's easy to test: in that buffer, do `C-h v indent-tabs-mode`.

If the value is non-nil, then check the code that you invoke to set up the makefile buffer - `makefile-mode` or whatever code sets up the buffer.  I'll bet that this is your problem.

Remember: `setq-default` sets the *default* value, which is the value the variable will have in any buffer, unless you set the (local) value to something else in that buffer.  Something is setting the value to non-nil in that buffer -that's my guess.  It's up to use to find that something.

If you cannot find it by checking the code that sets up the makefile buffer, then bisect your init file (and if necessary files, it loads) recursively to find the culprit.

Comment: @user1961679 Search/grep for `untabify` in your emacs init. Is it called in some hook that gets executed at the time of saving a file, like `before-save-hook`?

Comment: @kaushalmodi a 'C-h v' to see the value of before-save-hook var is (whitespace-cleanup), this function is quite long, does it do untabify?